# Python: print unicode string stored as a variable

Tags: python, json, string, unicode

In Python (3.5.0), I'd like to print a string containig unicode symbols (more precisely, IPA symbols retrieved from Wiktionary in JSON format) to the screen or a file, e.g.

```
print("\u02c8w\u0254\u02d0t\u0259\u02ccm\u025bl\u0259n")
```

correctly prints

```
ˈwɔːtəˌmɛlən
```

- however, whenever I use the string in a variable, e.g.

```
ipa = '\u02c8w\u0254\u02d0t\u0259\u02ccm\u025bl\u0259n'
print(ipa)
```

it just prints out the string as-is, i.e.

```
\u02c8w\u0254\u02d0t\u0259\u02ccm\u025bl\u0259n
```

which isn't of much help.

I have tried out several ways to avoid this (like going via `deocde`/`encode`) but non of that helped.

I cannot work with

```
u'\u02c8w\u0254\u02d0t\u0259\u02ccm\u025bl\u0259n'
```

either since I am already retrieving the string as a variable (as the result of a regex-match) and at no point in my code enter the actual literals.

It might as well be that I made a mistake during the conversion from the JSON result; by now I have converted the byte stream into a string using `str(f.read())`, extracted the IPA part via regex (and done a replace on the double backslashes) and stored it in a string variable.

Edit:
This is the code I had so far:

```
def getIPAen(word):
    url = "https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=" + word + "&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json"
    jsoncont = str((urllib.request.urlopen(url)).read())
    jsonmatch = re.search("\{IPA\|/(.*?)/\|", jsoncont).group(1)
    #print("jsomatch: " + jsonmatch)
    ipa = jsonmatch.replace("\\\\", "\\")
    #print("ipa: " + ipa)
    print(ipa)
```

After modification with `json.loads`:

```
def getIPAen(word):
    url = "https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=" + word + "&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json"
    jsoncont = str((urllib.request.urlopen(url)).read())
    jsonmatch = re.search("\{IPA\|/(.*?)/\|", jsoncont).group(1)
    #print("jsonmatch: " + jsonmatch)
    jsonstr = "\"" + jsonmatch + "\""
    #print("jsonstr: " + jsonstr)
    jsonloads = json.loads(jsonstr)
    #print("jsonloads: " + jsonloads)
    print(jsonloads)
```

For both versions, when calling it with

```
getIPAen("watermelon")
```

what I get is:

```
\u02c8w\u0254\u02d0t\u0259\u02ccm\u025bl\u0259n
```

Is there any way to have the string printed/written as already decoded, even when passed as a variable?

Comment: Please create a short, **complete** program that demonstrates the problem. Please copy-paste into your question the program and its output. See [mcve] and, more generally, [ask] for more information.

Comment: [Here](http://ideone.com/nEa33B) is an example program that produces your desired output.

Comment: @Robᵩ I added my full code to my post. Is ist okay like this? - I thought it would become too long then. Sorry for the inconvenience, it's my first post here.
For your example program: Thanks, it works - and actually my example does too, can't reconstruct at the moment why I thought it didn't or what I acutally had before explaining it that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have this value:

```
ipa = '\u02c8w\u0254\u02d0t\u0259\u02ccm\u025bl\u0259n'
```

because *that* value prints just fine:

```
>>> ipa = '\u02c8w\u0254\u02d0t\u0259\u02ccm\u025bl\u0259n'
>>> print(ipa)
ˈwɔːtəˌmɛlən
```

You *at the very least* have literal `\` and `u` characters:

```
ipa = '\\u02c8w\\u0254\\u02d0t\\u0259\\u02ccm\\u025bl\\u0259n'
```

Those `\\` sequences are **one** backslash each, but escaped. Since this is JSON, the string is probably also surrounded by double quotes:

```
ipa = '"\\u02c8w\\u0254\\u02d0t\\u0259\\u02ccm\\u025bl\\u0259n"'
```

Because that string has literal backslashes, that is exactly what is being printed:

```
>>> ipa = '"\\u02c8w\\u0254\\u02d0t\\u0259\\u02ccm\\u025bl\\u0259n"'
>>> print(ipa)
"\u02c8w\u0254\u02d0t\u0259\u02ccm\u025bl\u0259n"
>>> ipa[1]
'\\'
>>> print(ipa[1])
\
>>> ipa[2]
'u'
```

Note how the value *echoed* shows a string literal you can copy and paste back into Python, so the `\` character is escaped again for you.

That value is valid JSON, which *also* uses `\uhhhh` escape sequences. Decode it as JSON:

```
import json

print(json.loads(ipa))
```

Now you have a proper Python value:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(ipa)
'ˈwɔːtəˌmɛlən'
>>> print(json.loads(ipa))
ˈwɔːtəˌmɛlən
```

Note that in Python 3, almost *all* codepoints are printed directly even when `repl()` creates a literal for you. The `json.loads()` result directly shows all text in the value, even though the majority is non-ASCII.

This value does not contain literal backslashes or `u` characters:

```
>>> result = json.loads(ipa)
>>> result[0]
'ˈ'
>>> result[1]
'w'
```

As a side note, when debugging issues like this, you really want to use the [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) and [`ascii()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ascii) functions so you get representations that let you properly reproduce the value of a string:

```
>>> print(repr(ipa))
'"\\u02c8w\\u0254\\u02d0t\\u0259\\u02ccm\\u025bl\\u0259n"'
>>> print(ascii(ipa))
'"\\u02c8w\\u0254\\u02d0t\\u0259\\u02ccm\\u025bl\\u0259n"'
>>> print(repr(result))
'ˈwɔːtəˌmɛlən'
>>> print(ascii(result))
'\u02c8w\u0254\u02d0t\u0259\u02ccm\u025bl\u0259n'
```

Note that only `ascii()` on a string with actual Unicode codepoints beyond the Latin-1 range produces actual `\uhhhh` escape sequences. (For `repl()` output Python can still fall back to `\uhhhh` escapes if you terminal or console can't handle specific characters).

As for your update, just parse the *whole response* as JSON, and load the right data from that. Your code instead converts the `bytes` response body to a `repr()` (the `str()` call on bytes does **not** decode the data; instead you *doubly* escape escapes this way). Decode the bytes from the network as UTF-8, then feed that data to `json.loads()`:

```
import json
import re
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import quote_plus


baseurl = "https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles={}&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json"

def getIPAen(word):
    url = baseurl.format(quote_plus(word))
    jsondata = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8')
    data = json.loads(jsondata)
    for page in data['query']['pages'].values():
        for revision in page['revisions']:
            if 'IPA' in revision['*']:
                ipa = re.search(r"{IPA\|/(.*?)/\|", revision['*']).group(1)
                print(ipa)
```

Note that I also make sure to *quote* the `word` value into the URL query string.

The above prints out any IPA it finds:

```
>>> getIPAen('watermelon')
ˈwɔːtəˌmɛlən
>>> getIPAen('chocolate')
ˈtʃɒk(ə)lɪt
```

Comment: For the first issue (doing `ipa = \u...`), I can't figure out why I thought it didn't work or what the actual problem was before phrasing it that way, but as you say, this works totally fine. I'm sorry, don't know why I wrote it didn't.

Comment: For the second issue regarding the backslashes:
The string I extracted from JSON does not have double quotes but indeed the double backslashes, which I then, as I wrote, replaced by single ones (`.replace("\\\\", "\\"`) - if I left this away, it would print double backslashes. Therfore my string to be printed out does look like in the example that I posted, i.e. `\\u02c8w\\u0254\\u02d0t\\u0259\\u02ccm\\u025bl\\u0259n` which then prints the version with the single backslahes.

Comment: Your hint with `json.loads(ipa)` works - after manually adding double quotes - when I try it out just like this but not in my function and I can't see why at the moment. I'll add my actual code to my original post in a minute.

Comment: And thanks for the hint on `repr()` and `ascii()`, didn't know about that.

Comment: @lemontree: there, updated. You were mangling the JSON by causing a double-encoding. Don't call `str()` on a bytes object. Just decode the JSON instead and *work with the data given*.

Comment: @lemontree: it was your `str()` call that doubled the escape sequences; so from `b'\\u02c8'` to `"b'\\\\u02c8'"`; the `repr()` for a bytes object.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution does just what I wanted! I should have figured out earlier that the problem might be in the way I handled the JSON data, and wouldn't have come up with what you suggested myself. Now it works.

Comment: good answer. You could also mention that non-printable characters in `repr()` may be replaced with unicode escapes (relevant for printing collections, in a REPL), also `stderr` uses `backslashreplace` error handler. For example, `LC_ALL=C PYTHONIOENCODING=:backslashreplace python3 -c 'print("\u0254\u02d0")'` prints `\u0254\u02d0`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: added a small note about that, thanks.